# Which join should I use for this mysql query?

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I have a table 'PR' that has a specific TraceID and another table called 'BA' has a 'PAYMENT_ID' and (sometimes) a TraceID value that I have to extract from a column 'MISC' to then match the BA and PR Trace_ID.

Now, some records in BA do not have a TraceID after extraction BUT I still need these records to appear as rows.

PR table:

```
TraceID
178000
178001
178002
178003
```

BA table

```
PAYMENT_ID, MISC
100, AAA/TraceID=178000
101, BBB/TraceID=178001
102, Ref
103, CCC/TraceID=178002
104, Ref2
105, CCC/TraceID=178003
```

my output should be:

```
TraceID, PAYMENT_ID
178000, 100
178001, 101
NULL, 102
178002, 103
NULL, 104
```

etc..

I use this query:

```
   select * from
    (select TraceID from PR) PR
    left join 
    (select 
     PAYMENT_ID , if (locate('TraceId=',MISC)>0,SUBSTRING_INDEX(MISC,'TraceId=',-1),'') as traceID from BankingActivity ) BA
     on PR.TraceID = BA.traceID
```

I  only get the PR rows with a matching TraceID in BA.

Now, how should I modify query to get all PR records and their corresponding PAYMENT_ID  from BA (having same TraceID), but also all the PAYMENT_ID rows from BA without a matching TraceID?

I guess i should have a sort of UNION and then join, but all my attempts have failed

thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I don't understand the question, could you show sample input and desired results?

Comment: No one can help you if no one can understand you.

Comment: I added data for clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually want is a `RIGHT JOIN`, or alternatively, rewrite the query with the `BA` table first:

```
SELECT BA.PAYMENT_ID, PR.*
FROM (SELECT PAYMENT_ID,
      IF (LOCATE('TraceId=',MISC)>0,SUBSTRING_INDEX(MISC,'TraceId=',-1),'') AS traceID
      FROM BankingActivity) BA
LEFT JOIN PR ON PR.TraceID = BA.traceID
```